# How to create/use WCF services, so that they are stable in the long term?

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding, net-tcp

I'm trying to create WCF client-server application, which could run for days/weeks without intervention.

Here's how the client handles server interactions:

```
    static object myLock=new object();
    static MyService.IMyService myService;

    static void PerformServerInteraction(ref MyService.IMyService myService,  Action<MyService.IMyService> action)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            lock (myLock)
            {
                try
                {
                    action(myService);
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    LogException(e);
                }
                myService = new MyServiceClient(); 
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

        }
    }
```

`PerformServerInteraction` is called from several threads by the client app.

The server seems to run fine most of the time (no errors are displayed in log).

Server operation when invoked by the client takes several milliseconds tops.

For few hours, the apps run just fine. But after that, client calls start timing out on mass:

```
System.TimeoutException: The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.TimeoutException: The socket transfer timed out after 00:01:00. You have exceeded the timeou
t set on your binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected
 host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at .....my code
```

The issue persists untill I restart the client application or the server application. If I run several client applications, this kind of issue in one of the clients interferes with the other clients.

Here's server startup code:

```
try
{
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);
    //lets make sure that BW2 does not disturb the other software on the computer
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;

    //load the shedluer static constructor
    ServiceHost svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

    var tcpbinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

    //remove limits on the max array size
    tcpbinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
    tcpbinding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;

    tcpbinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
    tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
    tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
    tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
    tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;

    if (IsWindowsServer())
    {
        tcpbinding.MaxConnections = int.MaxValue;
    }

    var location = "net.tcp://localhost:12345";
    svh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), tcpbinding, location);


    // Check to see if the service host already has a ServiceMetadataBehavior
    if (!IsWindowsServer())
    {
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = svh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
        // If not, add one
        if (smb == null)
            smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        //smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        svh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        // Add MEX endpoint

        svh.AddServiceEndpoint(
            ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
            MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(),
            location + "/mex"
            );
    }

    svh.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Service maunted at {0}", location);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
    svh.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception");
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Why do I get this, and how can I avoid getting this in the future?

Comment: Once a service client proxy faults, you must call Abort() on the proxy and then create a new instance of it. Also, the service client proxies implement IDisposable, so you need to handle that as well.

Comment: Implemented your suggestion. Let's see if it works for at least a day )

Comment: Is the days/weeks of no interventions happening between service calls from the client or during a service call? If between service calls, try turning off session on the service. If the wait time is within a call, try setting the timeout high on both service and client.